# Is $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ bigger than $\omega$ in $NFU$ + infinity?

Tags: set-theory, alternative-set-theories

$NFU$ doesn't prove Cantor's theorem (that $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is cardinally greater than $S$) by a stratification dodge: the proof's critical step makes use of the unstratified formula $x \not\in f(x)$, so does not go through in $NFU$. In particular e.g. the universal set $V$ is as big as its powerset. However, something like Cantor's proof goes through to show that there is no bijection between e.g. $V$ and singletons of elements of $V$, since $\{x\} \not\in f(x)$ *is* stratified, so a version of Cantor's proof modified in obvious ways goes through.

$NFU$ also doesn't prove the axiom of infinity, by Goedel's second incompleteness theorem (it has a model in the natural numbers, as Jensen showed (!)). My question is, if we add the axiom of infinity ($\omega$ exists), do we know that $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is bigger than $\omega$? It seems to me that, without extra axioms (other than stratified comprehension, extensionality, infinity), we won't get this: we won't know anything more than that there are fewer singletons of natural numbers than there are natural numbers, by the same argument as that hinted toward above. Is this right? Seems likely wrong.

Comment: What is $\omega$ here -- the usual von Neumann ordinal, or an equivalence class of well orders? (Von Neumann ordinals don't seem to work well in NF, since even the successor function is not stratified).

Comment: It'll be an equivalence class as you say.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter actually: any infinite set will do.

Comment: Any infinite set? What about $V$?

Comment: $V$ isn't infinite w/o an axiom of infinity. I'm saying which infinite set we postulate the existence of doesn't seem relevant here. Question is: add "there exists an infinite set $S$" to $NFU$. Is the powerset of $S$ cardinally bigger than $S$?

Comment: Which definition of "infinite" are we using here? Dedekind's?

Comment: I'm not completely sure if it makes a difference - they might well be provably equivalent. I'll go with yes.

Comment: Of course it makes a difference.

Comment: Ah. I see. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: The answer is YES. The set $\omega$ of all naturals [in NFU+infinity] has a lot of properties that we can indirectly use to prove that its strictly less in size than its power. So despite we don't have Cantor's diagonal, we can still reproduce a similar argument by another route, its a matter of technicality. But the answer is YES. But on the other hand if you work in NFU + infinity, then $V$ is infinite, and the usual models for NFU  has $P(V)$ being strictly smaller in size than $V$. Actually proving that this is not the case is equivalent to Con(NF)

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't remember the detailed proof, but I think the answer is to fool the system, moreover to fool the typing. The idea is to define a relation in a stratified manner that sends every natural n to a singleton of a natural m. I remember something like this:

$T(|\{\{x\}|x \in m\}|)= \{|m|\}$  for every finite set m.

Now T is a "stratified" injection from $N$ to $P_1(N)$.

Since NFU proves that $|P_1(x)| < |P(x)|$ for every set x.[see *[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations#How_NF(U)_avoids_the_set-theoretic_paradoxes)*]

Thus $|N| < |P(N)|$.

The trick is that it is provable in NFU+Infinity, that every finite set
(i.e., an element of a natural number) is equal in size to a set of singletons.
This is proved by induction on naturals using property "has an element that is a set of singletons" [Since the set N of all naturals cannot be a subset of an element of any natural, since it's provably infinite in NFU + Infinity].

That said, clearly the domain of $T$ is $N$ (or $\omega$)